# USe Subquery to return columns from different tables

Tags: subquery

I want a sub query which returns columns from different tables
for example 
i am writing the code in the way similar to below

> Use North Wind Select *,(Select Order Id FROM dbo. Orders OI WHERE
>   OI.OrderID IN (Select OI.OrderID  FROM [dbo].[Order Details] OD WHERE
>   OD.UnitPrice=P.UnitPrice))AS 'ColumName' FROM Products P
>
> ERROR  : Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Sub query returned more
>   than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,
>   <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Whats the Mistake in this code 
please reply soon 
Saradhi

Answer (score 0):

> > Select Order Id FROM dbo. Orders OI WHERE OI.OrderID IN (Select OI.OrderID FROM [dbo].[Order Details] OD WHERE OD.UnitPrice=P.UnitPrice)

This query is returning more than one OrderId while it should be returning only one. See if your data is correct.

Comment: Hello Mohkhan , as far as i understand i am using "IN" in the query

Comment: I mean i am newto programming , can u suggest how to write the above query to get the result set as desired